# Installing Bootstrap in Rails MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm unable to use Bootstrap with a Rails app, although it was working for a short while at least.

I've downloaded the precompiled bootstrap files and copied them into the app folder. The gems I'm using are these:

```
gem 'bootstrap_form'

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

and the version of Rails is 5.1.2. I'm not sure if these gems are compatible with each other, but I have tried removing and updating them, but nothing has worked so far.

In my application.scss file I have

```
  *= require_tree .
  *= require_self
  *= require rails_bootstrap_forms

  */
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";
```

and in my application.js file I have

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require_tree .
```

When I try to open the app in local host the error reads- Sass::SyntaxError in Welcome#index.... File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

This seems to be a problem with importing the bootstrap files but I'm not quite sure why. Would be most grateful for any suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file **application.scss** to **application.css.scss**
In this way it will work for both **css** and  **scss**

In `Gemfile`:-

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
```

And remove the gem `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'`

You can use one gem out of the two.

Then precompile the assests as `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`